# Google Cloud organizational permissions - getting blocked form starting Shared VPC despite owner status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-networking

I am getting blocked from both the command line and console for starting a shared vpc despite me being the Owner and top of organization role.  Here are the error messages -

Required 'compute.organizations.enableXpnHost' permission for 'projects/******-core-dev'

q- how do i enable this then ???

and...

User [*********@****.com] does not have permission to access organization [********:setOrgPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: `Owner` is a legacy IAM role. The `Owner` role does not have all permissions. However, the `Owner` role grants you permission to assign more permissions to your IAM identity. Another item is that some roles are not available at the project level. You need to move up to the Organization level to grant some roles/permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you need the *Compute Shared VPC Admin* role. The permissions that contains that role are not included in the *Organization Admin* role.

In order to set this role to your account, you can follow the steps listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#nominating_shared_vpc_admins_for_the_organization).

Just as a tip, being *Organization Admin* does not mean you are "All Mighty" inside the organization and its resources. For some operations you need to grant extra permission to your user.

Give it a try and let us know if it worked c:

Comment: I couldn't see this role, as I was looking at project level IAM roles. This role is only available for the whole organisation.